# Develop a server based android application

Tags: android

I am going to develop a server based android application. In my app when a user enters for the first time it will show a window for registration. After the registration is completed, next time it will not show that registration interface rather the next interface. How can I do that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As you can see you got a minus point because you dont have any code and people think you dont effort anything. I suggest you go for research in google or buy a book about your question and ask specific question with some code effort. Also you can go for SharedPreferences or Sqlite. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some flag set in preference file after a successful registration and check it while launching the registration interface. Like within onCreate of registration interface or within a splash screen which determines whether to launch registration activity or normal content interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont have any code or any example of how this person will register (WebView, Button, whatever)

- You can save registration code or value to Shared Preferences, then if present do not display reg screen
- Or you can save the data to a sqlite database, same logic as above
- Or you can get reg information from the server and use same logic from above